# What is the purpose of decoupling capacitors near switching elements?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switches, filter, noise

I notice that, on a power supply, right near transistors and diodes that switch rapidly there are usually arrays of surface-mount ceramic capacitors with small capacitance (10nF, for example.)

I think these are called decoupling capacitors that take care of the high frequency noise. Big electrolytic capacitors are no good under high frequency as they behave like inductors due to their imperfections.

My questions are why is this high frequency noise generated by switches? Is it ringing during turn-on/offs? What are the benefits of reducing these fluctuations (such as reducing loss?)

Comment: The "high frequency noise" you're referring to is caused by high frequencies dropping voltage across the trace inductance. So decoupling switches is really no different than what you see for decoupling of ICs.

Comment: tldr; they counteract the inductance of the board traces.

Answer (score 1):

Without a decoupling capacitor, when an IC or circuit suddenly tries to draw more current, the additional current doesn't start flowing across the PCB trace right away, it takes time for the current flow to ramp up. During that period of time, the voltage would droop to a lower voltage at the load. The amount of droop is determined by the inductance of the PCB trace.

Additionally, when the current does start flowing, a bit too much comes at the load, and it overshoots the voltage. Each repetition of droop and overshoot gets smaller and smaller until it settles. This oscillation is called ringing.

Having a capacitor nearby causes the initial current surge to be taken largely from the capacitor, then the lowering of the capacitor voltage would draw more current from the PCB trace, the PCB trace sees a smoother transient of current increase, over a longer period of time, reducing the ringing.

The inductance of the leads of the capacitor are drastically lower than the inductance of all the PCB traces up to the power supply. This means that the device can rapidly vary its current without the voltage waving up and down.

Answer (score 0):

> *What is the purpose of decoupling capacitors near switching elements?*

Without a localized decoupling capacitor, current pulses taken by a high-frequency switching transistor will flow right back to the power supply through several hundred nano-henries of PCB tracks or wires. This causes EMI and, to avoid that, we place a low-ish value (but good quality) ceramic capacitor close to the switching transistor. It provides a localized current source (like a mini battery) for the transistor and allows proper circuit operation.

And, it largely prevents high frequency current pulses flowing all the way back to the power source or nearest bulk electrolytic capacitor. After all we don't want to emit RF energy in case we interfere with other people's electronics.

Comment: Just a minor point, the "quality" in this case is having low ESL; modest ESR (a low Q, or "quality" factor) may indeed be useful, as it dampens resonance with exactly that supply inductance.

Answer (score 0):

If the capacitors are far away, they are not effective, because longer wiring has larger inductance.

Basically, in a circut that simply turns on and off, the resistance defines how much current you can get, and the inductance defines how quickly you can get it.

In a switching application you need the current immediately, which is why the small bypass capacitors need to be close to switch to minimize inductance.

As current flowing in a loop is also an antenna coil, the capacitors are close to minimize the loop area.

Also, the switch is either on or off. It means voltages change fast, like a square wave. When looking at a time domain ideal square wave, in frequency domain it has frequencies up to infinity.

Ringing happens when stray capacitances and inductances are excited with a step edge of the switching square wave and they resonate at their natural resonant frequency.